# Узнать "вчерашний день"

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть дата 30.04.2018
Сегодня, допустим, 31.04.2018
Как через узнать, что это было вчера?

В моём случае "сегодняшняя" дата выводится так:

```
var dates = new Date();
var sDt = dates.getDate();
var sDm = dates.getMonth() +1;
var sDy = dates.getFullYear();
// fix
var sDt = sDt<10 ? '0'+sDt : sDt;
var sDm = sDm<10 ? '0'+sDm : sDm;
```

А дата, так скажем, элемента вытаскивается из html вот так:

```
<div class="date" data-date="30.04.2018">

var dateElem = $('.date').attr('data-date').split('.');
var dateElemDay = dateElem[0];
var dateElemЬMonth = dateElem[1];
var dateElemYear = dateElem[2];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511323/calculate-the-date-yesterday-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Допустим есть дата 30.04.2018
>
> Сегодня, допустим, 31.04.2018
>
> Как через узнать, что это было вчера?

Просто вариант:

```js
var yest = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
// Массив даты, соединяется в строку
var d = [yest.getDate(), yest.getMonth() + 1, yest.getFullYear()].join('.');
// Установить день
$('.date').attr('data-date', d).text(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date" data-date=""></div>
```

---

Вариант с вводом даты:

```js
var yest = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
// Массив даты, соединяется в строку
var d = [('0' + yest.getDate()).slice(-2), ('0' + (yest.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), yest.getFullYear()].join('.');

$('button').click(function(e) {
  var input = $('.chk').val();
  if (d === input) {
    $('.date').text('yesterday');
  } else {
    $('.date').text('Not yesterday');
  }

  console.log(input, d);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date" data-date="01.06.2018">&nbsp;</div>
<input type="text" class="chk" />
<button>Check date</button>
<div class="">dd.mm.yyyy</div>
```

---

Вариант без ввода даты:

```js
var yest = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
// Массив даты, соединяется в строку
var d = [('0' + yest.getDate()).slice(-2), ('0' + (yest.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), yest.getFullYear()].join('.');
// Date
var chk = $('.date').attr('data-date');
$('.date').text(d == chk ? 'yesterday' : 'other');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date" data-date="30.06.2018">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: @entithat а как удачно всё начиналось )

Comment: @KostaB., похоже я не так сформулировал.. Нужно узнать было ли это число вчерашним и так и вывести `.text('вчера')`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 внес правки.

Comment: спасибо большое)